# Error retrieving JSON data in node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to make an android app which displays the top command data on my AWS ec2 instance. The following is the node.js file I've written. It sends the top command result using a topparser npm module. And using the *checkCpuUsage* function, it sends a notification if cpu usage is more than 1%.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
var topparser=require("topparser");
var FCM = require('fcm-node');
var server = app.listen(8080);
var regTokens = [];
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
let data_builder = "";
const DEFAUT_TOP_DURATION = 2000;



function getTopData(callback, duration) {

    duration = duration || DEFAUT_TOP_DURATION;

    var top = spawn('top');
    top.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        data_builder+=data.toString();
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        top.kill();
        callback(topparser.parse(data_builder,10))
    },duration);
}


function sendServerData(req, res) {

    getTopData((data)=>{
        res.status("200").send(data);
    })

}

function checkCpuUsage() {

    getTopData((data)=>{

        var idl = data.cpu.idle;

        if(idl<99) {
            sendNotification(idl);
        }

    }, 2000)

}


function saveRegToken(req, res) {
    console.log("saveRegToken req body", req.body)
    regTokens.push(req.body.token);
    res.send(200);
}

let server_key =JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(('./config.json'))); ;

function sendNotification(idle){
    var idl = idle;
    var fcm = new FCM(server_key);
    for(i=0; i<regTokens.length; i++) {
        var message = {
            to: 'regTokens[i]',
            notification: {
                title: 'CPU Usage!',
                body: 'CPU Usage: ' + idl,
            },
        };

        fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
            if (err) {
                console.log("Something has gone wrong!");
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response);
            }
        });
    }
}

setInterval(()=>checkCpuUsage(),10000);

app.get('/sys', sendServerData);

app.post('/save_token', saveRegToken)

console.log("server listening on 8080");
```

I'm getting the following error in the checkCpuUsage() function:

```
var idl = data.cpu.idle;
                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'cpu' of undefined
at getTopData (/home/ubuntu/server_monitor/server1.1.1.js:38:17)
at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/ubuntu/server_monitor/server1.1.1.js:26:3)
at ontimeout (timers.js:469:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:304:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:264:5)
```

Following is an example JSON result from the topparser module:

```
    {
   process:[
      {
         pid:'1990',
         user:'alex',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'1560516',
         res:'90656',
         shr:'21864',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'6.1',
         mem:'12.5',
         time:'13:46.58',
         command:'cinnamon'
      },
      {
         pid:'5381',
         user:'alex',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'929508',
         res:'119792',
         shr:'8132',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'6.1',
         mem:'16.5',
         time:'11:14.11',
         command:'firefox'
      },
      {
         pid:'0245',
         user:'alex',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'24948',
         res:'1508',
         shr:'1056',
         s:'R',
         cpu:'6.1',
         mem:'0.2',
         time:'0:00.02',
         command:'top'
      },
      {
         pid:'1',
         user:'root',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'37352',
         res:'5688',
         shr:'488',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'0.0',
         mem:'0.8',
         time:'0:04.93',
         command:'init'
      },
      {
         pid:'2',
         user:'root',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'0',
         res:'0',
         shr:'0',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'0.0',
         mem:'0.0',
         time:'0:00.07',
         command:'kthreadd'
      },
      {
         pid:'3',
         user:'root',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'0',
         res:'0',
         shr:'0',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'0.0',
         mem:'0.0',
         time:'0:54.23',
         command:'ksoftirqd/0'
      },
      {
         pid:'4',
         user:'root',
         pr:'20',
         ni:'0',
         virt:'0',
         res:'0',
         shr:'0',
         s:'S',
         cpu:'0.0',
         mem:'0.0',
         time:'0:00.00',
         command:'kworker/0:0'
      }
   ],
   task:{
      total:194,
      running:1,
      sleeping:193,
      stopped:0,
      zombie:0
   },
   cpu:{
      user:0.9,
      system:3.1,
      ni:0.1,
      'idle':95,
      wa:0.3,
      hi:0.6,
      si:0,
      st:0
   },
   ram:{
      total:727308,
      used:664028,
      free:63280,
      buffers:7600
   },
   swap:{
      total:753660,
      used:309516,
      free:444144,
      cachedMem:187424
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here :

```
var top = spawn('top');
top.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    data_builder+=data.toString();
});

setTimeout(function() {
    top.kill();
    callback(topparser.parse(data_builder,10))
},duration);
```

You are trying to call the callback using a timeout which is bad practice. Instead, You call the callback from inside the stdout.on('data') hence, making sure that function is called and there is data available before calling the callback.

Like so :

```
top.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    data_builder+=data.toString();
    top.kill();
    callback(topparser.parse(data_builder,10))
});
```

Ideally, Using promises would help to make the code more readable and structured.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly pointing `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cpu' of undefined`

It means here your `data` is `undefined`. Here you are not getting data from your `getTopData()`.

You can check this two lines `data_builder+=data.toString();` or `topparser.parse(data_builder,10)`

Add some console statements, You will get the idea.

**SUGGESTIONS** :

Be consistent in your code. Somewhere you are writing plain JavaScript syntax and somewhere in `ES6`

Make a habit to follow any one.